# Dotnet Core - Finding all the files in a folder relative to the one you are in and then finding the csv file added last

Tags: c#, .net-core

So relative simple.. should have been able to cobble together something but I am stuck on relative directory paths and finding the actual latest file.

I found this

```
 var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
 var latestFile = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

Then I realised I wasnt sure how to reference the file two directories down from the current class.

Further, `.OrderByDecending` does not exist on `GetFiles`....

Here is the directory layout... I am working in `DATASuburbInitialiser`:

[image]

How do I obtain relatively (that will also work in a release mode) the latest csv file in the `SuburbCSV` directory?

I would use a `resx` file but it was noted that you had to stop application and its a web application that needs to stay up and I need to update suburbs from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

1. [GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netcore-2.2) returns an array which most certainly should allow for usage of `OrderByDescending` once you've captured all the files you're looking for. You should add a reference to `System.Linq` in your class and target only CSV files by using a search pattern like `directory.GetFiles(*.csv)` though I would opt for `EnumerateFiles` so you don't collect an array of items you don't intend to do anything with.
2. The folder's location in runtime is not relative to the current class. It's relative to wherever the app is executing from. That's most likely a bin folder, and you can experiment with relative paths such as `..\..\SUBURB.Initialisations\SuburbCSV`, adding '..\', and other parent folders as needed. You can also leverage `SearchOption.AllDirectories` once you're sure you have a parent directory which has the files in some sub-folder and you don't really care to look in a specific sub-folder. I would only do that in testing, however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add** the using "`using System.Linq;`" in your .cs File.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna follow the expression "stop talking, show me your code", so here's my self-explanatory code.

```
class Program
    {
        static List<FileInfo> GetFiles(string path, bool recursive = false)
        {
            List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            files.AddRange(di.GetFiles());
            if (recursive)
            {
                var directories = di.GetDirectories();
                if(directories.Length > 0)
                    foreach(var dir in directories)
                        files.AddRange(GetFiles(dir.FullName, true));
            }
            return files;
        }
        static List<string> OrderByCreation(List<FileInfo> files, bool descend = false)
        {
            IOrderedEnumerable<FileInfo> orderedfiles = null;
            orderedfiles = descend
                ? files.OrderByDescending(item => item.CreationTime)
                : files.OrderBy(item => item.CreationTime);
            return orderedfiles.Select(item => item.FullName).ToList();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = GetFiles(@"C:\MyDirectory", true);
            var files = OrderByCreation(list, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why convert it to a list? You should return an enumerable, queryable, etc. so the caller can decide if they want to store all of the results, get a count, or just grab the first result. The benefit of doing this with EnumerateFiles (especially with using a search pattern) is that you're not storing so many items in memory that you don't want to do anything with.

Comment: In my case I need the lot as its for the complete set of Australian suburbs... but point taken..